# What type of projects is better to be developed by ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

These days my friends recommend me to use **ASP.NET MVC**, instead of **ASP.Net Web-forms**.
But I'm not Optimist to it.

I consulate about this problem and my friends said me that these two technologies have their own place in web programming zone, according to the **project type**.
Now I want to know what **type** of projects are better to be developed by **ASP.Net MVC**?

and the 2nd question, In your opinion is it conceivable that Microsoft **abandon** this technology?

Comment: About two years ago we decided to switch from Webforms to MVC. 
We do mainly Business Applications and I must say that we are very happy with MVC. 
Cleaner code, more flexibility and no viewstate headache ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays i always use mvc for all my new projects it is much more cleaner code. And you dont have to rely on asp.net web controls i dont think web controls render nice html. 
Plus that you dont have to think about viewstates.

ASP.NET mvc can apply on all type of projects it is more the way how you like too code then which type of project. Thats my opionen.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt very much it will be abandoned any time soon.

MVC is a different way of working and probably more suited to a kind of developer as well as a kind of project. It gives better control over your markup and front end code, forces better practice for separation of concerns and hands over a lot more power over how the site works.

This is a broad subject and better suited to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

If you rely a lot on the ASP.NET Web Controls then you may find MVC difficult to get to grips with at first.